# recyclerview inside a tablayout is only called once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

i have a recylcerview inside a tablayout, and tablayout is inside fragment (navigationview)
my problem is, recyclerview is only display/called once (initial startup of the app). after
switching to other navigationview and returning to the previous tablayout with recyclerview,
the recyclerview is not called anymore.

here is my code :
first tablayout

```
private fun setupViewPager() {
    if (Singleton.sa != null) {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(Singleton.sa!!)
        adapter.addFragment(FirstFragment(), "Recently Added")
        tab_viewpager.adapter = adapter
        tab_tabs.setupWithViewPager(tab_viewpager)
    } else {
    }
}

internal inner class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager):
    FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {

    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check Fragment's LifeCycle you will understand how/when to update Recyclerview with Tabular View.

Anyway, you can add a function in your onResume() to update your recyclerview items or call api.

```
  @Override public void 
    super.onResume();
    yourMethod();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found answer in this since no one could answer it.

instead of using

```
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(parent's context/activity)
```

use,

```
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```